# Visual C++ 2010 Express for mac

Tags: c++

Is it possible to get Visual C++ 2010 Express for Mac OS X?
If not is there another application, other than Xcode, that will do the same thing?

Comment: If you run Windows in Virtualbox/Parallels/VMWare Fusion, you can run VC2010 Express. Otherwise, try [Eclipse with CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/), which will use GCC as the compiler. If you're trying to build Windows software however, you will need to use a compiler targeting Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio C++ is not supported on OS X.

You can use either Eclipse or KDevelop. A complete listing IDEs for C++ is available at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B

Answer (score 2):

There is no Visual Studio for Mac that I'm aware of. I think QtCreator, Eclipse and NetBeans all work on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a version of Visual Studio which is cross platform. It will run on Windows, Mac OSX and Linux. It is called Visual Studio Code. You can download it at: https://code.visualstudio.com/download

You will have to download the C++ extensions. It will take you to the market place where you can get the extension for free.

Personally I prefer Xcode when coding on a Mac.

It's not hard to learn, but because it is fairly new there aren't many useful videos or articles on how to navigate Visual Studio Code. If you are familiar with Visual Studio IDE for Microsoft Windows, Visual Studio Code is a totally different program.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Eclipse: 
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers-includes-incubating-components/indigor

Answer (score 0):

If you really want visual c++ bootcamp you MacOS. Install windows along side with Mountain Lion and you are good to go.